# Error: Non-Static method gettext() cannot be refrenced from a static content in EditText.getText().toString();

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, clipboardmanager

I am trying to add a button that will copy the text and i got this error. What is static content. what should i use if I can't use this?

```
cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    String text;
                    text=EditText.getText().toString();

                    myClip=ClipData.newPlainText("this is the text", text);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text Sucessfully Copied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling EditText.getText().  getText() is not a static function.  You need to call getText() on an instance of an EditText object.
Something like

```
(EditText)view.getText()
```

Same thing with ClipData.newPlainText.  You've got to have an object instance before you can call that one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to bind your editText by using findViewByID() method and then;

Instead of this,

```
EditText.getText().toString();
```

Try to use this:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)
yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

Simply it's necessary to find the view by ID from your XML layout. Then, you do your work with it.

Comment: couldn't get that. please explain a little bit more.